# Aero failure and errors after power loss

Tags: windows-7, power, themes, aero

After a recent power loss I experienced, I rebooted (more slowly than usual) to find that Windows Aero failed to load (a High Contrast theme was loaded similar to Windows Classic and Aero themes were disabled) in addition to an error stating that a system service enabling logon of standard users had failed (this computer has no standard users). I restarted the computer again (slightly faster) to find all errors gone and my Aero themes loaded again. I am still somewhat nervous about this, and I am unsure what should be done about it.

Configuration: Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit SP1 with discrete AMD Radeon graphics and a four-core Intel i5-2410M processor.

Comment: My guess.  Windows detected it crashed and booted into a limited mode.  Since you restarted the computer.  The normal mode was able to load properly.  Without more information we would be just guessing

Answer (score 0):

After getting a second opinion, it seems that Ramhound's suggestion seems to be the case; the computer booted into a modified safe mode to protect system services. I had never experienced this behavior before, however; is this the result of Windows Update or something else?